# How to create an UDP Broadcast listener socket on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sockets, udp

I'm trying to develop a Windows Phone 7.5 application and I want to create a listener socket to listen to UDP Broadcast messages on port 8001.

I have modified the example [How to: Create and Use a UDP Socket Client Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202864%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) but I was getting an "Invalid argument exception" but I fixed that error.

This is my code now:

```
    public String SecureRecive(int portNumber, bool isBroadcast)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg;

        Send("melnibone", portNumber, " ", isBroadcast, out socketEventArg);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        if (!isHasSent) ;
        return Receive(portNumber, isBroadcast, socketEventArg);
    }

    private string Send(string serverName, int portNumber, string data, bool isBroadcast, out SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg)
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";

        // We are re-using the _socket object that was initialized in the Connect method
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            // Set properties on context object
            if (isBroadcast)
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, portNumber);
            else
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(serverName, portNumber);

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This event handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                response = e.SocketError.ToString();

                // Unblock the UI thread
                _clientDone.Set();
                isHasSent = true;
            });
            // Add the data to be sent into the buffer
            byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);

            // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
            _clientDone.Reset();

            // Make an asynchronous Send request over the socket
            _socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);

            // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
            // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
            //_clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            socketEventArg = null;
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Receive data from the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="portNumber">The port on which to receive data</param>
    /// <returns>The data received from the server</returns>
    private string Receive(int portNumber, bool isBroadcast, SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg)
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";

        // We are receiving over an established socket connection
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            if (isBroadcast)
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, portNumber);
            else
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);

            // Setup the buffer to receive the data
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This even handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                    // Retrieve the data from the buffer
                    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                    response = response.Trim('\0');
                }
                else
                {
                    response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                }

                _clientDone.Set();
            });
            // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
            _clientDone.Reset();

            // Make an asynchronous Receive request over the socket
            _socket.ReceiveFromAsync(socketEventArg);

            // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
            // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
            //_clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }
```

But I don't know how to set socket timeout to infinite.

Is it possible to create this kind of sockets on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go in order:

1. Does the above code work? You said you fixed the "Invalid argument exception" problem however my guess is that it still doesn't work as expected, this for the reasons in the next points
2. You cannot "listen" on a socket on Windows Phone 7, for security reasons you can only receive from an IP you initiated a communication with, so send first an empty packet and then listen for a limited amount of time.
3. UDP broadcast is not supported, only TCP, UDP unicast and UDP multicast.

I hope the above three points sum up the main issues with your code.